# Local domain points to localhost without /etc/hosts entry

Tags: apache, localhost

I recently created domain on my local laptop called mhtest.dev. I entered it into sites-enabled on apache, as I routinely do, and then tried to access it. It worked. I didn't question it at the time, but later on I realised I hadn't actually entered mhtest.dev into /etc/hosts file. How does it know that mhtest.dev should look at my local IP?